Как работает присваивание типа данных в Python?
На ввод дается 6 цифр
Надо найти сумму первых трех
x1 = list(map(int, x[:3]))
print(sum(x1))

Это правильное решение
Мое решение выглядит так:
x = list(input()) 
x1 = x[:3]
print(sum(x1))

Почему нельзя сделать так?
Если я вызову команду вывода на экран x1, он выдаст список
Если я вызову команду вывода типа переменной print(type(x1)), он покажет list
Получается это обыкновенный список, почему тогда я не могу найти сумму его значений и вывести ее?
Консоль ругается на неверный тип данных, говорит нужен int или str:
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'


В ошибке говорится что нельзя складывать строку с числом

Первая строка первого кода эквивалентна такому коду x1 = [int(z) for z in x[:3]] а во втором коде нет преобразования в int.

Функция input() возвращает строку, а не список целых чисел. Чтобы исправить это, вам нужно преобразовать каждый символ строки в целое число.
x = list(map(int, input().split()))  # Преобразуем ввод в список целых чисел
x1 = x[:3]
print(sum(x1))

Используем map(int, input().split()), чтобы разделить ввод по пробелам, преобразовать каждый элемент в целое число и затем создать список из этих целых чисел. Теперь код должен правильно суммировать первые три элемента списка x.

Ну кстати не сказано, что на вход подается 6 цифр через пробел, написано просто про 6 цифр. Скорее всего просто 6 цифр слитно. В примере решения просто берутся последние 3 символа, и каждый преобразовывается в int.
